# Filtered sub-folders counts

Tags: filter, counter, folders

How would you show "unread" count on sub-folders after filtering an entity? Do you know any commonly used examples of such?

Think of it as a mailbox that has 100 unread email. Then we have 4 subfolders: work, home, holidays, other with 25 in each. When I filter this entity I have 10 of each. My question is: Should it say HOME (10) or HOME (25); as well as INBOX (100) or INBOX (40)

Here I made an example.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp7cm6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Once used, the filter should be very prominent and there should be a very visible button to clear it.

Then you have two options:

1. Show only the number of the items matching the filter;
2. Show the found items over the total number of messages: 25/100.

The first option would be the cleaner but in case the user gets distracted during the task, she may be a little confused when returning back to it at a later moment.

The second option has the advantage of being very clear but the disadvantage of needing more horizontal space of your tabs.

Either way the filter has to be designed in such a way that it's easily visible once used.